# How to make more than two jQuery scripts work in a single webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[-Test link for the problematic webpage-](http://www.ultimatemango.com/umfinaldraft/bai2/index.html)

This webpage is a landing page to a parent website. There are several javascripts that are required to run. Unfortunately, not all work simultaneously. I have tried various combinations but cannot find a way to make the webpage work.

The functions taking place in the webpage are:

- Revolutionary Slider
- Multiplication calculator
- tabs toggler
- smooth scroll-to-section menu
- back-to-top button
- Fancybox (lightbox)

Please help . Thankyou

Comment: Andre - suggest that you group all your external scripts together on the page and place the "jquery.min.js" script first (before all others). Check the documentation for the libraries that you are using on the page.  They might have other dependencies in addition to jQuery. So the order in which you load them on the page might cause a problem. If the documentation is unclear, then just try changing the load order to see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Errors generated by your page

[image]

indicate that jQuery library is not the first script you are loading.

Looking into source show that you are loading jQuery in line 75.
Move this line to very top of your page.

[image]

I think this is your primary problem. Your scripts may not necessarily require different jQuery versions.